# Persistent chat room login

Tags: bug, chat

**Background**

Two days ago, I was going through the list of SE chat rooms to find some funny/weird stuff. In the end, I wasn't disappointed. Some of the rooms I found were [Aww!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2110/aww) and [Prayer Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8080/prayer-room).

**How did the bug happen?**

I went to a lot of rooms and then after I finished I clicked "leave (**all**)" and I successfully logged out of all the rooms.

I went to my usual room ([The DMZ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz)) only to see that I'm still in that "Aww!" room.

[image: Aww]

**What have I tried?**

I've tried clearing my cookies, manually logging out of the room, clearing my cache, using another computer, clicking "leave", clicking "leave (**all**)", clicking on the little up arrow next to the room's name (the room disappears, and comes back after a few seconds).

Comment: Letting the cuteness get the better of you, are we?

Comment: just to be clear, "leave" and "all" are two different links.

Comment: @Xarcell That's why I said _clicking "leave", clicking "leave (**all**)"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of a sudden, while I was in a chat room, the "Aww!" room disappeared as if I clicked the arrow next to its name.

It's been like that for 7 hours, I think it has fixed itself.